# How can I prove the annihilation electron positron can't generate positron + muon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

How can I prove the process $e^{+}+e^{-}\rightarrow e^{+}+\mu ^{-}$ doesn't happen?

Comment: You must first display good-faith efforts to exclude it at tree level in the SM. You must then provide a crude  estimate of a one-loop effect.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about **Flavor-changing neutral current**. Below is such a process (just replace tau lepton with muon in your case):

[image]

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current):

"Flavor-changing neutral currents may occur in the Standard Model beyond the tree level, but they are **highly suppressed by the GIM mechanism**. Several collaborations have searched for FCNC.The Tevatron CDF experiment first observed the FCNC decay of the strange B-meson to phi mesons in 2005.

FCNCs are generically predicted by theories that attempt to go beyond the Standard Model, such as the models of supersymmetry or technicolor. Their suppression is necessary for an agreement with observations, making FCNCs important in model-building."

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most formal answer you could be provided, but you can easily check and see that *lepton conservation* is not properly respected in that process. We begin our annihilation process with *two* electron type particles, namely an electron and a positron, and finish with *one* electron type particle and *one* muon type particle, whereas if we check, we can see that there was no muon type particles in beginning of the diagram.